# Tie Google Analytics to Marketo Cross Domain Sub Domain Tracking API?

Tags: google-analytics, marketo

We are currently using Marketo for our landing pages but it is not the same domain as our company site. We are also using Google Analytics.

We have used this [guide](https://www.demandlab.com/insights/blog/the-ultimate-google-analytics-and-marketo-integration-guide/) to tie our Analytics session to our anonymous or known Marketo record by inserting the Marketo User ID as a Google Analytics User ID and added the Marketo User ID dimension & set the scope as User.

Per this article, if we would like to have our Lead ID be recognized on non-Marketo landing pages, like our Corporate website, that we will need to do some extra API connections. Has anyone done this with success? I found that there is some Cross Domain Sub-Domain Tracking located [here](https://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-subdomain-tracking-in-google-analytics).

Would I only need to tie the visit to our corporate site to the Marketo Sub-Domain site visit as stated in the link above, which would then be tied to the MarketoID dimension that we just made shown in the first link provided?

Not sure what to do to make this happen or if it is as simple as doing the cross domain sub-domain tracking.

Apologies if I am not making any sense.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely.

Are you trying to link/merge a known Marketo record on one domain to an anonymous Marketo record on another domain, and then pass that single Marketo record ID to Google Analytics?

This would involve matching the Munchkin cookies on both domains to Marketo records, probably via the REST API, then merging the two records.

Once you have merged the records from the two domains, you could pass this single Marketo ID to Google Analytics, using the same ID for both domains.

#### Resources:

1. http://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/lead-tracking/api-reference/#munchkin_associatelead
2. http://developers.marketo.com/blog/get-a-visitors-cookie-id-and-then-query-associated-lead-data/

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a javascript that capture the GA ID and MKTO cookie and store them in a databased. Then, sync the database with mkto and append the GA ID to the lead record.

We've developed a tool that does that automatically, without any coding and allows you to track leads/visitors cross devices and domains.
Check it out: https://gapidu.com/